# Entropy of monotone increasing bounded functions

Tags: statistics, entropy

So I have made a theorem about the entropy of monotone increasing bounded functions (the proof is for my thesis). The theorem states that the entropy of the class generated by these functions is finite. I couldn't find any false statement in it as could my supervisor, but then I saw an exercise in the book "Empirical processes in M-estimators" which contradicts my theorem. The exercise states: "Verify that the class G = {g : R --> [0, 1], g increasing} is not totally bounded for the supremum norm on R". Besides that, I discovered this: [Show that the space of increasing, bounded function is not totally bounded w.r.t. $\sup$-norm](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2990351/show-that-the-space-of-increasing-bounded-function-is-not-totally-bounded-w-r-t). Therefore my theorem has to be wrong. I would like to know what is wrong about my theorem and if I could change that with a particular condition.

I had my proof made in latex, so I could only make a screenshot.
[My proof of the theorem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4pOE3.png)

Thanks for your help

Comment: Is the exercise in the textbook using the same meaning of "bounded" as you are? Specifically, the collection of "bounded" functions is not the same as the collection of functions "bounded by some fixed $M$."

Comment: The exercise states:
2.2 Verify that the class G = {g : R --> [0, 1], g increasing} is not totally bounded for the supremum norm on R.

Comment: Hence it is bounded by 1

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think the issue is that you construct your net based on a particular function $f \in \mathcal{F}$ (in particular, the $a_i$ depends on this $f$), which may not work well for approximating other functions from $\mathcal{F}$.

Comment: That is possible, but I don't know how I could resolve that issue. Do you have any suggestions? I also found this which contradicts my theorem:
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2990351/show-that-the-space-of-increasing-bounded-function-is-not-totally-bounded-w-r-t